# PHP nested while loop

Tags: php

I tried to do a `while` inside a `while` to print a multiplication table like,

```
1  2  3  4  5
2  4  6  8 10
3  6  9 12 15
4  8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

But I got only 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

#### Code:

```
$i = 1;
$x = 1;
while($i <= 5){
   while($x <= 5){
     echo $i * $x;
     $x++;
   }
   echo "<br>";
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: You need to reset `$x` (missing `$x =..`).

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Amout of same answers is really high.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you're not resetting `$x` when the inner loop completes its iteration. Try this instead:

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 5) {
  $x = 1;
  while($x <= 5) {
    echo $i * $x;
    $x++;
  }
  echo "<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset `$x`, so:

```
$i = 1;
$x = 1;
while($i <= 5){
    while($x <= 5){
        echo $i * $x;
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1; // added this line
    echo "<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Output:

> 12345  
>   246810  
>   3691215  
>   48121620  
>   510152025

*You can then do what ever you want to format it.*

---

---

*More elabrate explanation:*

- **First run:**

It enters both outer and inner loops, showing the desired output for the first line. You end up with `$i = 2` and `$x = 6`.

---

- **Second run:**

Since `$i` is `2`, it doesn't leave the outer loop, but `$x` is `6`, so it doesn't enter the inner loop again.

---

- **Last* run:**

It then keeps adding `1` to `$i` until it doesn't match the outer loop condition anymore and leaves you with that unwanted result.

Comment: This could also be achieved using `for`: [**https://3v4l.org/s7fJE**](https://3v4l.org/s7fJE)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

This is because you have not `initialized` your `$x` after external `while loop` completes its one `cycle`. so after one cycle `inner loops` does not run

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while($i <= 5) {
  $x = 1;
  while($x <= 5) {
    echo $i * $x;
    $x++;
  }
  echo "<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO ONLINE](https://eval.in/597575)**

**php code:**

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 5){
  $x = 1;
  while($x <= 5){
    echo $i * $x." ";
    $x++;
  }
  echo "<br/>";
  $i++;
}
```

**result:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 6 8 10 
3 6 9 12 15 
4 8 12 16 20 
5 10 15 20 25
```