# Why while loop works like this?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, cycle

I thought, that I understand something in programming... But I don't understand the example below...

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
while($i<5){
    while($j<5){
        echo "$i $j; ";
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

The output I expect: "0 0; 0 1; 0 2; 0 3; 0 4; 1 0; 1 1; 1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 0 0; 2 1; 2 2; 2 3; 2 4; 3 0; 3 1; 3 2; 3 3; 3 4; 4 0; 4 1; 4 2; 4 3; 4 4;".

The output I get: "0 0; 0 1; 0 2; 0 3; 0 4;".

Why is that?

Comment: Why do you expect that output ?

Comment: Because I forgot to set j to 0 before "while". for-loop habits:)

Comment: I see, you tried a funny way to try to get that result! :)

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097501/php-nested-while-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set `j` to `0` once, outside of both loops.

By the time `i` goes to `1`, `j` is already `5` and you do nothing to set it back to `0`.

```
$i = 0;
while($i<5){
    $j = 0; // $j should be here
    while($j<5){
        echo "$i $j; ";
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: True story:) Thank you!